# Unable to upgrade to Magento 2.1.0 GA via command line

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, magento-2.1

**I've already applied the patch MDVA-532.**

When I run `composer update magento/magento-composer-installer` I got this error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package magento/product-community-edition == 2.0.6.0 could not be found.
>
> Problem 2
>       - Installation request for braintree/braintree_php == 2.39.0.0 -> satisfiable by braintree/braintree_php[2.39.0].
>       - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 requires braintree/braintree_php 3.7.0 -> satisfiable by
>   braintree/braintree_php[3.7.0].
>       - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 requires braintree/braintree_php 3.7.0 -> satisfiable by
>   braintree/braintree_php[3.7.0].
>       - Conclusion: don't install braintree/braintree_php 3.7.0
>       - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.0].
>
> Potential causes:
>
> - A typo in the package name
> - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see
>     https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more
>     details.
>
> Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for
>   further common problems.

---

When I run `composer update` I got this error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for magento/data-migration-tool ~2.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/data-migration-tool[2.0.5, 2.0.0, 2.0.2,
>   2.0.7].
>       - Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 100.1.0
>       - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 requires magento/framework 100.1.0 -> satisfiable by
>   magento/framework[100.1.0].
>       - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 requires magento/framework 100.1.0 -> satisfiable by
>   magento/framework[100.1.0].
>       - Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 100.1.0
>       - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.0].

Comment: How did you install Magento 2 originally? Via github repo?

Comment: I installed it via create `composer create-project`

Answer (score 2):

I've bumped into the same issue. Any attempt to upgrade to version 2.1 bumped into various messages like "Conclusion: don't install magento/module-widget" or "Can only install one of". Closer inspection of all packages defined in my `composer.json` showed that it was calling for various modules of version `100.0.*` while actually the upgrade messages mentioned that version `100.1.x` was needed.

I changed all instances of `100.0.*` to `100.*` and this allowed me to upgrade.

Note that I assume that this versioning scheme follows the semantic versioning standards, meaning that this allows me to upgrade to newer minor versions without breaking backwards compatibility. Also note that I've run this on various development sites, where I'm just developing Magento 2 extensions. I don't have any Magento 2 project, so don't care much about the core. It might be that my `composer.json` hacks are not meant for production.

Comment: Did you try something like this: `composer require magento/magento-composer-installer:100.1.0` followed by `composer update`? But if you already applied the patch I don't think you have to do that.

Comment: Yes, adding a `composer require` for every single package would work also. But that's the same as editing `composer.json` manually. There are about 20 packages that jumped from `100.0` to `100.1`, so I modified `composer.json` directly.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer but this thread helped me to find my problem!
I tried to upgrade Magento from 2.0.4 to 2.1.0
Applied the 532 patch. And followed the docs from http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/tech_bull_21-upgrade.html and http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html
But was getting this problem:

```
- The requested package "magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 exists" as magento/product-community-edition[2.0.4] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

Only after I have found this topic, restored my composer.json and run

```
composer update magento/magento-composer-installer
```

And then 2 usuall update commands, it became working!